# Best way to write events to a file coming from kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

I'm creating a nodejs library that reads events from kafka and pushes them into a file. The plan is to push data until the file reaches, for example, 100MB (or 2000 events). My questions are:

- Is there already a library that does this?
- If there isn't, I was thinking about doing the following:

1 - Read the event from kafka and transform it.
2 - Push the data into an array.
3 - Have a second thread reading from that array and pushing it to the file using writeStream.

Is there a better option?

Thanks,
Luís

Comment: No need for a thread.  Just call `stream.write(...)` when you have the transformed data.  The stream will take care of sending the data when it can as it does everything asynchronously.  If you're pushing data very quickly, you will have to pay attention to flow control on the stream (when the `stream.write(...)` returns `false` and you have to wait for the `drain` event before writing any more.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically need Nodejs, you could use Kafka Connect FileSink or HDFS/S3 connectors to write events to local files. The HDFS and S3 sinks have a `flush.size` setting to write a minimum number of events to each file.

You can use MinIO or Apache Ozone as an S3 compatible filesystem, or the HDFS connector would use `file://` URI rather than needing to run HDFS.